# How to get all the data from a CURL GET APII from Windows

Tags: windows, loops, curl, get

I have to use save Data from an API.  So I'm using a script ".cmd" using cURL. My problem is to use/keep/save all the data (all the lines), I think my example will be more simple :

```
curl --request GET --url https://SITE.fr/data/v1/connections?since=2017-10-01^&until=2017-10-09 --header "Authorization:$TOKEN">"F:\ADRESS\file.json"
```

I have only data from the 2017-10-01 and not all the day. I don't have the others days. Did anyone know if I have to add something on the script to have all the data like a maximum line = 2000000 ?

How can I have more ? I think I have to use a loop, but I don't know how...

I found a "X-Total-Pages" thing but I don't know how to use it.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Thank you Pratik GADOYA for the edit ;)

Comment: I can use a loop like this : for /l %%x in (1, 1, 100) do (
curl   --no-sessionid --insecure --basic --request GET --url https://WEB/data/v1/connections?since=2017-10-01^&until=2020-12-31 --header "Authorization: %token%">C:\FILE\ListeCx%%x.json
   echo %%x )
1 = first page, 1 = one page, 100 = X-Total-Pages for example... But I don't know how to know the X-Total-Pages and how to put the number of page... For now, if i do the loop, I have every time the same results

Comment: I found a partial solution : curl -I  --no-sessionid --insecure --basic --request GET --url WEB/connections?since=2017-10-01^&until=2018-01-01 --header "Authorization: %token%">C:\Files\Lis.json  I obtain the number max of pages, so after I do this : FOR /L %%B IN (0,1,327) DO (
curl  --no-sessionid --insecure --basic --request GET --url WEB/connections?since=2017-10-01^&until=2018-01-01^&page=%%B --header "Authorization: %token%">C:\FILES\ListeConnexions2017-%%B.json
ECHO %%B
)  And I have all the pages, I don't succeed to past the Number max into a variable %%M for example...